# Equal height with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Friends,
I have a little project and two columns in my div and I want to make equal these divs if right div bigger than left div so I wrote a code for that it's work as I want but in my project it's not going to work properly why I didn't understand.

and I want to share my demo

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/NgbKYe)

and in my project[image]

as you see my image height is: 169px and my right divs height is: 193px so where is my mistake you think ?

```js
function getListHeight() {
    $(".tur-list .col-lg-5 img").each(function() {
        var getTurHeight = $(this).parents(".tur-list").find(".col-lg-7").outerHeight();
        var getLeftHeight = $(this).parents(".tur-list").find(".col-lg-5 img").outerHeight();
        if (getTurHeight > getLeftHeight) {
            $(this).outerHeight(getTurHeight);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  getListHeight();
});
```

```css
.box{
  width:700px;
  margin:30px auto;
}
.tur-list{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
img{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="box">

<div class="box">

<div class="tur-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
     <figure>
       <img src="http://content.anitur.com/web/images/240x220/2016-12/yurtdisi_tur_Sq4MvAMnDGjz7rAgEaOIbalkan-sehirleri-turu-4.jpg"/>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
      <div class="tur-list-title">
        <h3>This is the title</h3>
        <p>p of title</p>
      </div><!-- title -->
      
      <div class="tur-location">
        <p>Netherlands</p>
      </div><!-- location-->
      
      <div class="tur-list-detay">
        <p>some details here</p>
      </div><!-- detail-->
      
      <div class="tur-bottom-detay">
        <a href="#">Link of box</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis unde voluptatibus ea, possimus totam blanditiis molestiae doloremque ipsa magni maiores fugit? Impedit expedita aspernatur dignissimos ipsa consectetur accusamus praesentium, saepe, fugit incidunt doloribus. Maxime expedita nesciunt, magni accusamus culpa saepe cupiditate tempora cum soluta natus, ea illo quo! Nulla error repudiandae natus vel dicta sequi molestias, possimus optio a dolore laboriosam eligendi impedit nam dolorum! Temporibus necessitatibus alias ullam reiciendis ipsam id quisquam, repudiandae? Quas doloremque, laboriosam quaerat sed veniam, dolores ea aspernatur velit, accusamus eligendi soluta rerum architecto cum fuga? Explicabo assumenda quisquam laudantium quae laborum voluptatem alias harum!</p>
      </div><!-- bottom detail-->
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="tur-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
      <figure>
      <img src="http://content.anitur.com/web/images/240x220/2016-12/yurtdisi_tur_Sq4MvAMnDGjz7rAgEaOIbalkan-sehirleri-turu-4.jpg"/>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
      <div class="tur-list-title">
        <h3>This is the title</h3>
        <p>p of title</p>
      </div><!-- title -->
      
      <div class="tur-location">
        <p>Netherlands</p>
      </div><!-- location-->
      
      <div class="tur-list-detay">
        <p>some details here</p>
      </div><!-- detail-->
      
      <div class="tur-bottom-detay">
        <a href="#">Link of box</a>
        <p>another thinks.. bla bla..</p>
      </div><!-- bottom detail-->
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)?

Comment: older browser it's not support flexbox and our clients mostly are old that's why

Comment: may be use plugin? http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: woow I didn't know it before there is a such a plugin thanks

Comment: so how will I use this ?

Comment: yes I used this but same issue I have this one too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var biggesthei = 0;

    $(".col-lg-5 img, .col-lg-7").each(function () {

        if ($(this).outerHeight() > biggesthei) {
            biggesthei = $(this).outerHeight()
        }

        if ($(window).width() < 100) {
            $(this).outerHeight() = biggesthei

        }

        $(".col-lg-5 img, .col-lg-7").css("min-height", biggesthei);
    });
     });
```

```css
.box{
  width:700px;
  margin:30px auto;
}
.tur-list{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
img{
width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="box">

<div class="box">

<div class="tur-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
     <figure>
       <img src="http://content.anitur.com/web/images/240x220/2016-12/yurtdisi_tur_Sq4MvAMnDGjz7rAgEaOIbalkan-sehirleri-turu-4.jpg"/>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
      <div class="tur-list-title">
        <h3>This is the title</h3>
        <p>p of title</p>
      </div><!-- title -->
      
      <div class="tur-location">
        <p>Netherlands</p>
      </div><!-- location-->
      
      <div class="tur-list-detay">
        <p>some details here</p>
      </div><!-- detail-->
      
      <div class="tur-bottom-detay">
        <a href="#">Link of box</a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis unde voluptatibus ea, possimus totam blanditiis molestiae doloremque ipsa magni maiores fugit? Impedit expedita aspernatur dignissimos ipsa consectetur accusamus praesentium, saepe, fugit incidunt doloribus. Maxime expedita nesciunt, magni accusamus culpa saepe cupiditate tempora cum soluta natus, ea illo quo! Nulla error repudiandae natus vel dicta sequi molestias, possimus optio a dolore laboriosam eligendi impedit nam dolorum! Temporibus necessitatibus alias ullam reiciendis ipsam id quisquam, repudiandae? Quas doloremque, laboriosam quaerat sed veniam, dolores ea aspernatur velit, accusamus eligendi soluta rerum architecto cum fuga? Explicabo assumenda quisquam laudantium quae laborum voluptatem alias harum!</p>
      </div><!-- bottom detail-->
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="tur-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
      <figure>
      <img src="http://content.anitur.com/web/images/240x220/2016-12/yurtdisi_tur_Sq4MvAMnDGjz7rAgEaOIbalkan-sehirleri-turu-4.jpg"/>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
      <div class="tur-list-title">
        <h3>This is the title</h3>
        <p>p of title</p>
      </div><!-- title -->
      
      <div class="tur-location">
        <p>Netherlands</p>
      </div><!-- location-->
      
      <div class="tur-list-detay">
        <p>some details here</p>
      </div><!-- detail-->
      
      <div class="tur-bottom-detay">
        <a href="#">Link of box</a>
        <p>another thinks.. bla bla..</p>
      </div><!-- bottom detail-->
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

> Equal height using jquery

```
function equalHeight() {
    var biggesthei = 0;
    $(".tur-list .col-lg-5 img, .tur-list .col-lg-7").each(function () {

        if ($(this).height() > biggesthei) {
            biggesthei = $(this).height()
        }

        if ($(window).width() < 640) {
            $(this).height() = biggesthei

        }

        $(".tur-list .col-lg-5 img, .tur-list .col-lg-7").css("min-height", biggesthei);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
        equalHeight();
    }):
    $(window).resize(function () {
        equalHeight();
    });
```

Comment: thanks Ayatullah but I couldn't worked it: https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/zzoGOg

Comment: yes thank you I see but this set all div same height for example some of my div can be 500 height or 300 height maybe 100 height and my condition is if `.col-lg-7` is bigger then `.col-gl-5` then do this bla bla

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but non will be easy.

One way to do it, with no need to use JavaScript/jQuery:

1. Use table layout. (HTML)
2. Set the image as the background of the left column. (CSS)
3. Set the background image size to 100% width 100% height, which will give you the stretch looking, or use the "background-size: cover;" effect. (CSS)

The concept as following:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="
            width: 40%;
            background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            ">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 60%;">
            text<br>
            text<br>
            text<br>
            text<br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here's a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/evilReiko/pq2xkqbw/)

Comment: my web site is responsive and that's why I can't use table to responsive them basically thanks

Comment: Who said tables cannot be responsive? And it's easy. Set the table and the rows to `display: block`, and set table-cells (td) to `display: inline-block` or `float:left`, bingo, you got a responsive table :)